How to define base url for Remix application?
I create simple SPA Remix application:
npx create-remix@latest --template remix-run/remix/templates/spa
then run:
npx remix vite:dev
dev server works ok:
➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173
though when i define base url according to the documentation:
vite.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
  base: "/foo/",
  plugins: [
    remix({
      ssr: false,
      future: {
        v3_fetcherPersist: true,
        v3_relativeSplatPath: true,
        v3_throwAbortReason: true,
      },
    }),
    tsconfigPaths(),
  ],
});

➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/foo/
the application cannot find root.tsx any more:
ErrorResponseImpl {
  status: 404,
  statusText: 'Not Found',
  internal: true,
  data: 'Error: No route matches URL "/foo/"',
  error: Error: No route matches URL "/foo/"
...

How can i define base url for Remix application so it could be deployed under arbitrary context path: http://localhost:8080/foo?

looks like adding basename:"/foo" after ssr:false in vite.config.ts solves the problem of resource loading. All scripts and ccs are found and loaded w/p, though the page does not get hydrated only content of HydrateFallback is rendered.
If i remove base and basename the app start working properly and client side code does get executed

Correction: on dev server:  npx remix vite:dev the app works w/p with and without base url, but when i build SPA prod : npx remix vite:build and transfer content of build/client to my server static/ folder it does not work without any errors. (all js/css resources are loaded properly)
